# Running Eclipse 4.11 with Java 12

Tags: java, eclipse

Have installed Java 12 and updated Eclipse to 4.11. I note that eclipse has changed in that the 'MarketPlace' and 'Contribute' menus have disappeared preventing the addition of add-ins. Main problem is that Java 12 enhancements are not recognised; the compiler compliance setting does not go beyond 11. Any  Java 12 code such as new switch statement is marked as an error.

Have checked that Java 12 is running (even removed Java 11). Java 12 is recognised under 'Installed JRE's' but not listed under 'Execution emvironments' but is listed under 'Compatible JRE's'. I have been to https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.11-P-builds but this ultimately requires the installation of add-ins but the market place is not in the menu.

Comment: [Link explains the Java 12 integration with Eclipse 4.11](https://superuser.com/questions/1427518/how-to-enable-java-12-support-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I installed a package from Eclipse Marketplace. Here is the link.

[Eclipse Java 12 support for 2019-03 development stream](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-12-support-eclipse-2019-03-411)

After installing, here is the screen capture of my Java compiler preferences.

[image: Eclipse 4.11.0 Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for prompt answer. In order to add the Market Place I had to load the welcome screen as it was not in the Help menu. It was also necessary to add --enable-preview as a start option. I tried adding to various .ini files but nothing worked. Eventually, hovering over my error code, a suggested fix was offered and that worked after a restart of eclipse. I could now select compliance level 12 as per the previous answer. I also checked the 'Enable Preview' checkbox. Everything now works.
I will attempt to find where the start option is stored and why I get an error message "JRE Oracle Corporation/12 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled." although this does not stop my application from running.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the root cause is in `JDK` 13 installation. After i installed it for the 1st time I found that it is invisible. Only after sequential uninstall and re-install `JDK` and manual `JAVA_HOME` and Path to jdk bin and pushed windows update it appeared finally in installed software list.

`JDK` installation process asks to close `Eclips` to continue installation but, it seems, does nothing with this opportunity